# hola amigos. Tengo una tabla vacia

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, django-views, django-templates

Tengo una tabla vacia, cuando la renderizo en el template los elementos vacios me imprimen por pantalla "None", necesito que el espacio este en blanco por favor me ayudan.
Intentte esto y no funciono:
[image: ! gracias !]

Comment: y como te podemos ayudar si no sabemos como traes los datos ni como los envias al template? Por favor agrega más detalles y coloca el código como texto

Comment: Hola @Camilo. Realmente debes poner el código o el querry con el que traes la consulta, no una foto, debe de ser escrito, así lo podemos reproducir y ayudarte de una forma más certera. También te invito a leerte la sección de cómo preguntar en este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, con esto te evitas malos comentarios, que eliminen tu pregunta y lo más importante que te puedan responder. Éxitos y Bienvenido a la comunidad.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lectura altamente sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola, leyendo un poco tu código estaba viendo que estás consultando de la siguiente manera:

```
x.id == "None"
```

Lo cual en Python es incorrecto, la forma correcta para saber si una variable contiene un valor None es con el operador 'is' de la siguiente manera:

```
x.id is None
```

El cual en caso de que x.id sea None, devolverá True, de lo contrario False.

Comment: Aunque se agradece la intención, procura no responder a preguntas de baja calidad (en este caso, el OP subió imágenes en lugar de código, lo cual es [mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976)). Además, se le pidió gentilmente que modifique su pregunta, y (aún) no lo ha hecho. Lee [answer].